# How to find strengths of weapons and armour in PC Rogue?

Tags: rogue

Everything about the game is "available" within the game.  But how do I know what's better -- a mace, a longsword, two-handed sword?  plate or ring mail, and how much do bonuses close the gap?

I tried looking online at online resources, but none of them seem to be able to answer this definitively.  I can't even find a good table.  I'd use a guide's table if necessary, but I hope there is a way to find all of this out in-game?